# How to count in template (not forloop)?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have forloop in my template and i use forloop.counter but in this case:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.name %}
        {{ forloop.counter }} - {{ item.name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

forloop failed. It shown:

```
1 - bla, bla
5 - woo, woo
...
```

How to count only visible items?

Comment: is items always the same type? If so what is the type of items?

Comment: How is visibility/nonvisibility marked for items? Also, can you make your view pass a `visible_items` list to the template context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When confronted with this problem, I would pass a "list of visible items" to the template.  If you need both lists on the page for some reason, then pass both lists to the template.  One is just a filtered queryset of another.

Comment: I think this would be the best solution. However, if for some reason, Nips does not want to use this solution, writing a (very) simple template filter to filter out the elements he doesn't want to display would do the trick.